# Android JCIF SMB

Tags: java, android, jcifs

I'm working with Smb in the Android SDK.

I have the next code:

```
public AuthListFiles() throws Exception {

1        SmbFile file = new SmbFile("smb://DOMAIN;USER:PASS@ROUTE");

2        SmbFile[] files = file.listFiles();

3   //     for( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    //        System.out.println( " " + files[i].getName() );
    //    }
4   //     System.out.println();
    }
```

The problem is in the line 2. If I execute a programa like a Java Application runs correctly, buy if I use this in a Android application it has an error.
Has anyone used the JCIF library with Android?

The error is:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/10.67.0.10

jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:802)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:948)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:309)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:364)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

What does this means `Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/10.67.0.10`?

In a normal Java appication this runs.

Comment: **What** error are you getting?

Comment: The application Beta1 has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.        I cannon fix the error because I cannot debbug the project. I just working with Eclipse in that.

Comment: Sorry, the error are as follow:

The error is: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/10.67.0.10

jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:802)

Comment: at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:948)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:309)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:364)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
What means Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/10.67.0.10?

In a normal Java appication this runs.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Error: "Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.xx" can be caused by improperly configured NAS. For routers with DD-WRT firmware, go to Web interface and set Services - NAS - Samba - Public Share to 'Enable'.